# 19.10: Using incron with an external drive

Tags: 19.10, incron

I have a folder on an external drive, into which I wish to drop certain files which will automatically be processed once they are written.

I have an [incron](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man5/incrontab.5.html) trigger set up which works for this quite nicely, so long as incrond is started after the drive is mounted. Unfortunately, it appears that even if the drive is present at boot time, it is not mounted until after incrond has started.

This means that the folder does not exist when incrond starts, so the watch fails to create.

If I restart incrond once everything is started up, then it all works fine, but I would like to have this work automatically.

Is there a way I can get incrond to restart automatically when the drive finishes mounting? or some other way to achieve the same effect.

The drive is usually but not always available at boot, so arranging for incrond to start after the mount takes place would at least be an improvement.